# Please help me optimizing this Linq statement

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Can help me to optimize the following LINQ statement. I'm using NHibernate as ORM. This statement is taking more than a minute to execute. It shouldn't take that much time.

```
 var inValidIntroductionDates = environment.IntroductionDateInfo.IntroductionDateDetails
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDate)
                                .Where(x => x.VaccineDetail.Id == vaccine.Id &&
                                            x.ViewInfo.Id == viewInfoDetail.ViewInfo.Id &&
                                            x.MasterForecastInfo.Id == scenarioId &&
                                            x.IsIntroductionDateValid == false)
                                .ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: Pull out the SQL generated from the logs and run a query excecution plan on the SQL database. I suspect large numbers of rows and incorrect indexes

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Where` clause before `OrderByDescending` to reduce the number of records participating in the order by statement. Like

```
var inValidIntroductionDates = environment.IntroductionDateInfo.IntroductionDateDetails
                               .Where( x => x.VaccineDetail.Id == vaccine.Id && 
                                     x.ViewInfo.Id == viewInfoDetail.ViewInfo.Id && 
                                     x.MasterForecastInfo.Id == scenarioId && 
                                     x.IsIntroductionDateValid == false)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDate)
                                .ToList();
```

Also you can change

```
 x.IsIntroductionDateValid == false
```

to

```
 !x.IsIntroductionDateValid
```

But that would not improve the performance. Just a readiblity option.

Comment: Sorry!! no luck its taking the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inValidIntroductionDates = environment.IntroductionDateInfo.IntroductionDateDetails.Where(
                        x => x.VaccineDetail.Id == vaccine.Id && x.ViewInfo.Id == viewInfoDetail.ViewInfo.Id && x.MasterForecastInfo.Id == scenarioId && x.IsIntroductionDateValid == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDate).ToList();
```

first find, then order

Comment: Sorry!! no luck its taking the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

- Please attach a profiler to your database and tell us how the exact
  statement that is sent to the database
- Find out if the statement is executed slow or if nHibernate processing takes the time
- if it is the database query: optimize for the statement (e.g. index, execution plan,...)
- if too many queries are executed: combat the n+1
- if it is nHibernate execution: Turn off nHibernate logging

Please let us know what's the point.

Regards,
Michael